# Faster drawing in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I got program that draws spaceship 
(Turtle Graphics) forward,backward etc.

By using a lot of orders and lines drawing spaceship takes 5 seconds using turtle.speed(0).

And whenever you click the right/left key it draws it again in other direction. 
It major thing in my project. 
Is there a way to draw it faster?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Switch from turtle to something that supports sprites and bliting.

Comment: @Liam 2.7 ahi. Typically though

Comment: No but thanks for the good words on my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `turtle` has a draw delay of 10 milliseconds. Every time it updates the canvas, it will pause 10 milliseconds as a simple way of controlling the animation speed. This delay is independent of the speed of the turtle itself. If you want to speed up the animation, you can set a shorter delay, e.g. with `turtle.delay(3)` or `turtle.delay(0)`.

Note that turtle graphics are more of an educational tool than a serious way to do graphics. If you don't have a specific reason to use `turtle`, consider switching to other graphics libraries.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `screen.tracer(n)` where a bigger `n` value means a faster drawing speed but less details